# Why is my blender model/mesh not connected in some places?

Tags: mesh, rigging, blender-internal-render-engine

I have a model and rig I have been working on. [image: enter image description here]e]

For the most part it is completed however I have an occurring problem that  hinders my progress on this as well as other models I have attempted to finish: [image]

In addition to certain parts of the model not moving in unison as shown above, certain parts also seem to stretch.[![enter image description here]

I've attempted joining the parts of the mesh with control J however it does not seem to help. Would anyone know what I am possibly doing wrong and be able to provide me with help?

Comment: Looks to me like it might be an issue wit weight painting.

Comment: you have to weight paint on this bone while the neck/head bone is selected

Comment: You seem to have failed to upload the third image you intended to add.

Comment: I have tried but when I do this it just creates more problems. While everything now moves with the mesh the pieces that once immobile now only stretch, similar to the mouth.